# Cordova - Asynchronous SQLite queries and flow of control

Tags: sqlite, cordova, asynchronous

I'm using Ionic Framework with the `ngCordova` module.
I store a list of objects in a `SQLite` database.

My problem is that the queries are asynchronous. So I'm using lots of callbacks to get the results.
But I also should load a view showing a list of these objects (stored in the database). This view can be opened by the user in every moment pressing a button (so a callback doesn't work in this case). How could I ensure that my data are ready? I'd like to wait for the query result and then allow to load the view, but I can't find a way.

May you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Where is the problem? Just make your SQLite query and in the success callback you put the logic to generate the view.

Comment: @Joerg I don't have to open the view when the query returns. The view can be opened in every moment by the user pressing a button.
I load the data at the boot, but how can I ensure that when the user presses the button the query has returned? I'd prefer to avoid flags. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options:

- Use a splashscreen and hide it when query is finished
- Hide your content and show a spinner until the query is finished
- Hide the button until the query is finished
- Disable the button until the query is finished

Comment: I solved using AngularJS "Resolve" and Promises. I think it's the clearest solution!
In this way the state doesn't load until the promise returns.
More information here: https://thinkster.io/egghead/resolve

Thank you!